# Postgres: Composite Unique Index with a value

Tags: postgresql, indexing

```
CREATE TABLE article (
   day integer,
   is_chosen boolean
)
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX day_is_chosen_unique_index ON article (day, is_chosen);
```

The above will give me an unique index on the two columns, which means on a given day we can have one article that is chosen and one article that is not chosen.

I need to the unique index for the is_chosen field only. In other words, on any given day, we can only have one article that is chosen and multiple articles that are not chosen

Maybe something like this:

`CREATE UNIQUE INDEX day_is_chosen_unique_index ON article (day, is_chosen true);`

How would I go about creating this composite index?

Comment: *"we can have one article that is chosen and one article that is not chosen"* Looks more like you can have many days, each of which can be both chosen and not chosen.

Comment: @samol Did you try the proposed solution? Consider accepting the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This partial index will suffice:

```
CREATE TABLE article (
    id          INT
,   when_day    INT
,   is_chosen   BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE
);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX day_is_chosen_unique_index
    ON article ( when_day )
    WHERE is_chosen;
```

Note: 'DAY' is reserved keyword in SQL so better not to use it as a column name.

Comment: Here's the documentation for partial indexes: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/static/indexes-partial.html